# Synchronizing perforce if all conflicts can be resolved

Tags: batch-processing, perforce-client-spec

I would like to write a batch file that would sync perforce only if there is no conflict, or if all conflicts would be resolved. I cannot find any option to do that in p4 sync or p4 resolve.

Thanks